# Managing monorepo versioning using modified version of semver in a python project

Tags: python-3.x, microservices, monorepo, semantic-versioning

Consider you have a `monorepo` in github, whereas each folder represents a microservice.
Now I want to be able to have a git tag for each microservice separately.
Since we are sharing one repo, each tag for example `v1.0.0` for microservice `foo1` will capture this tag from being created for microservice `foo2`.

Instead, we can create tags named `foo1-v1.0.0` and `foo2-v1.0.0` to solve this collision.
My question if we have some nice package or tool for doing precisely this convention- meaning semver with some prefix?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

This can be achieved with Reliza Hub - entirely on the free plan - as following (disclaimer - I'm working on the tool):

1. Create a project in Reliza Hub for every sub-project that you have in monorepo and set its versioning to semver - http://docs.relizahub.com/get-started/#create-first-project
2. Create an organization-wide API Key - in Reliza Hub, navigate to the Organization Settings menu, click on the Programmatic Access tab and click on the plus-circle icon on the bottom. Then choose Org-wide Read-Write for your key type.
3. In GitHub Actions set secrets for API ID and API Key obtained above.
4. Use reliza-get-version action step for every project you have, referencing its project id - https://github.com/relizaio/reliza-get-version .
5. reliza-get-version action will output full version and short version (short version is guaranteed to work with container image tags) - in semver they should be the same.
6. Once you have the version variable, simply add path prefix and do a `git tag` step

Overall, your action would look something like below:

```
on: [push]

name: Get Version and Tag

permissions:
  contents: write

jobs:
  foo1:
    name: Version foo1
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - name: Reliza Hub Get Version
        id: get-version-foo1
        uses: relizaio/reliza-get-version@1.4
        with:
          reliza_api_id: ${{ secrets.RELIZA_API_ID }}
          reliza_api_key: ${{ secrets.RELIZA_API_KEY }}
          path: foo1
          reliza_project_id: 00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000
      - name: Git Tag Version
        shell: bash
        run: |
          git tag foo1-${{ steps.get-version-foo1.outputs.reliza_full_version }}
          git push origin foo1-${{ steps.get-version-foo1.outputs.reliza_full_version }}
  foo2:
    name: Version foo2
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - name: Reliza Hub Get Version
        id: get-version-foo2
        uses: relizaio/reliza-get-version@1.4
        with:
          reliza_api_id: ${{ secrets.RELIZA_API_ID }}
          reliza_api_key: ${{ secrets.RELIZA_API_KEY }}
          path: foo2
          reliza_project_id: 00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000001
      - name: Git Tag Version
        shell: bash
        run: |
          git tag foo2-${{ steps.get-version-foo2.outputs.reliza_full_version }}
          git push origin foo2-${{ steps.get-version-foo2.outputs.reliza_full_version }}
  foo3:
...
...
```

P.s. This can be further optimized, i.e. by creating a small mini-action containing both steps, but this would also depend on other things you want to do there. I.e. see how we use it in our build docker image action - coupled with other things happening in there - https://github.com/relizaio/reliza-docker-action/blob/master/action.yaml

Comment: thanks but I need to be able to save the work internally without being exposed to third party hubs, using only github and some python package for doing it

Comment: Note that the end result will be fully preserved locally in the form of git tags here - meaning you won't lose any existing data for your use case even if 3rd party is removed completely.

Answer (score 0):

If your package feed is fully SemVer compliant, you can use the build metatag:

1. Package the microservices separately.
2. Apply the commit hash from which they were built to the metatag in the package version string (v1.0.42+commitId)
3. Tag the commit hash with the package name and full version string (MicroserviceA v1.0.42+commitId).

Sadly, not all package services (NPM comes to mind) are SemVer compliant and often drop the metatag, arguing that it is not used for sorting. Also, not all version automation can do repo tagging with a prefix other than 'v'.